# Removing an element from FiniteSet

Tags: python, sympy

While I was working on a module in `sympy` I came up with a problem that how do I remove a specific element from `FiniteSet`. Like

```
>>> f = FiniteSet(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> f
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

If I try to remove `2`, how would I do that.

I tried to convert it to a list and used `remove()`, but I was unable to convert back the `list` to `FiniteSet`.

I did not found any function that would do the task. Might be possible that I would have missed something, but I thought better to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract desired elements:

```
from sympy import FiniteSet
f = FiniteSet(1, 2, 3, 4)
f -= FiniteSet(2)
print f
```

Output: `{1, 3, 4}`

Answer (score 3):

Use in-place exclusive-or (symmetric difference):

```
In [7]: f = {1, 2, 3, 4}

In [8]: f ^={2}

In [9]: f
Out[9]: {1, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-=` operator

```
import sympy
a=sympy.FiniteSet(1,2,3,4)
print(a)
a-=sympy.FiniteSet(2)
print(a)
```

output:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{1, 3, 4}
```

Or you can always convert it back into a `set` to do the removing.

```
a=sympy.FiniteSet(1,2,3,4)
a=set(a).remove(2)
a=sympy.FiniteSet(*a)
```